# Accordion animation in ui-bootstrap is different from the original bootstrap (size of the accordion is increased, visually it "jumps")

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css-transitions, angular-ui-bootstrap, accordion, css-animations

The default animation in [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-example-accordion) does not change the size of the full accordion in the process. For some reason in the [ui-bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/accordion) that is not the case and while it animates it does a strange increase in size which looks like it "jumps" (easy to notice if you look at the bottom of control). I think that the original behaviour is way more pleasant to the eye as the ui-bootstrap may even change the scrollbar size while it's animating.

Why is it doing it differently and is there an easy way to fix it? E.g. by changing the template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The accordion-group template uses the uib-collapse directive to open/close the panels, see [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/template/accordion/accordion-group.html#L7)  Removing the uib-collapse directive will bypass some of the unexpected behavior you are seeing, but I think you will need to manage closing/opening the panels.

Comment: I have tried adding ng-class="{in: isOpen}" instead of uib-collapse, that does work, but removes the animation alltogether ( .panel-collapse {
 transition: height 0.35s ease; 
}) did not help. I am not sure how to add it back in a default bootstrap way?